# Is it legal to reverse-engineer free US government software?

Tags: copyright, software, licensing, us-federal-government

The US government provides a number of closed-source software packages to the public for free. Some packages are explicitly listed as "public domain"; other packages list a specific agency as the copyright holder. Packages might be written by US government staff, contractors, or both.

These programs frequently contain EULA language forbidding decompilation or reverse engineering. Since the software is given away for free by the government (i.e. the US government does not profit from the software it releases), the reasoning for that EULA language is not entirely clear to me, and I wonder about its validity.

Is is legal to decompile or otherwise reverse engineer free, publicly available software from the US government? Has a case ever been brought against someone for reverse engineering such software?

Comment: "other packages list a specific agency as the copyright holder": this strikes me as odd, since works of the federal government are explicitly in the public domain in US copyright law.  Can you point to an example?

Comment: @phoog one example is RASPLOT, which lists `Copyright: FEMA` in the `About` dialog, and makes no mention of being Public Domain. This struck me as odd, too. https://www.fema.gov/rasplot-version-30

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Copyright status of works by the federal government of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_status_of_works_by_the_federal_government_of_the_United_States) lists some scenarios in which the US government can hold copyright, including those of work produced by a contractor or otherwise assigned after creation to the US government.  Additionally, the copyright may be intended to apply in other jurisdictions, in which case the applicability of the license agreement may depend on whether one is in the US or not.

Comment: Is there reason to suspect the answer is any different from reverse engineering any other piece of software?  Because there's a whole process for that involving multiple teams.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy what do you mean by "a whole process for that involving multiple teams"? I suppose I'm thinking that things might (or should, in my opinion?) be different in the case of the US government because there's no profit incentive.

Comment: @user321321 [Clean room design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design), which is basically when you have one team that disassembles code in a way which, if used directly, would almost certainly be a copyright violation.  But then they write up some specification and hands it to the second team, the "clean room", who proceed to implement the software/whatever with no actual knowledge of the original copyrighted works, or dependency on copies thereof, etc.

Comment: [The case law gets pretty complicated](https://www.eff.org/issues/coders/reverse-engineering-faq#faq4), and there are certain fair use exemptions which can be hard to figure out if they are applicable to what you're doing or not.  But most relevant here seems to be that if the EULA forbids you from reverse engineering, then you are forbidden from it and you waive your fair use exemptions by accepting the agreement.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy makes sense. Thanks so much for the input.